# Expressjs - Duplicate GET requests on the same URL (one type document, one type text/html)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm currently using nodejs and express to try and add a piece of middleware that renders a landing page for Internet explorer users. My issue is the browser seems to be making a duplicate GET request to the homepage whenever I load it.

Here is an overview of what's going on:

**app.js**

```
var routes = require('./routes.js');

var express = require('express'),
    helmet = require('helmet'),
    handlebars = require('express-handlebars'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

//...

var ieRedirect = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.method, req.path);
    if(req.headers['user-agent'].indexOf("MSIE") >= 0){
        res.render('IE-landing-page', {layout: 'default'});
    }   
    else{
        next();
    }   
};

app.use(express.static('./public', { extensions: ['html', 'htm'] }))
    .use(helmet({contentSecurityPolicy: false,}))
    .use(cors())
    .use(cookieParser())
    .use(ieRedirect)
    .use(routes);

app.listen(config.app.port);
```

**routes.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

var users = require('./routes/users.js'),
    notFound = require('./routes/404.js');

//...

router.get('/', users.home);

//...

router.get('*', notFound.error404);

module.exports = router;
```

**users.js**

```
module.exports = {
    home: function(req, res){
        //...
        //ends with:
        return res.render('home', {layout: 'default', user: userInfo});
    }
},
//...
```

So as I understand it, I've configured my app to use the middleware with `.use(ieRedirect)`, when a request is received it should be checked for an IE user agent, otherwise sent to the router. The router file registers the routes and directs the traffic to the right function using `.get(...)`. However, the line in my middleware `console.log(req.method, req.path);` is logging:

```
GET /
GET /
```

Whenever the homepage is loaded. Why is this second request occurring?

Having a look at the chrome console network tab, the first request is for the `/` URL, status 200 and type "document". The second request occurs later and is again for `/` but this time is of type "text/html".

Since the path is just `/` it's clearly not an issue with favicons (and commenting out favicons does not prevent the issue from occurring).

How can I prevent this second request from being made?

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out not to be with express or the backend at all. In one of my handlebars templates, I had the following placeholder for an image which would be filled by an API:

```
<img src="#" alt="">
```

The # src was causing the browser to look for `/#` which was the source of the additional request. Removing the src tag entirely fixed this issue.

Can't believe this was such a headache. Hopefully someone else who's having the same issue finds this.